# Asynchronously apply list of python functions to single argument

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I'm familiar with python's `multiprocessing.Pool` and the associated `map` and `map_async` calls.  `map` and `map_async` take a single function and apply it to iterable of arguments.  I'd like to do the reverse -- take an iterable of functions and apply them to a single argument.  Is there a simple standard idiom for this kind of operation?

In other words, I'm looking for something like the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(4)
functions = (add, subtract, divide, multiply)
args = (1, 2)
result = pool.fmap(functions, args)
print result
# [3, -1, .5, 2]
```

Comment: Are you trying to subclass `Pool` and create a new method, or will a separate function suffice?

Comment: Either is fine -- I'm just looking for a clean solution to what I would expect to be a fairly common operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So.. I would suggest using the existing framework and flipping it on its head. You could do something like the following:

```
from functools import partial

def operation(args, operator):
    return operator(*args)
final_op = partial(operation, [1,2])
```

This is more or less equivalent to dano's solution, but I find the use of partial here to be a way to really preserve generality and avoid the brittle nature of accessing arguments by index. It also makes things cleaner on the side of actual usage:

```
pool = Pool(4)
print pool.map(final_op, (add, sub, div, mul))
```

Comment: This is the kind of clean, idiomatic solution I was looking for.  

Also, hello Slater.

Comment: @MadisonMay always happy to help :) Tell the guys I say hi.

Comment: You can't do it using a `lambda`. You'll get a `PicklingError`. You have to create a top-level function: `def operation(args, operator): return operator(*args)`. Using the partial is nicer than the list comprehension, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, div
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fmap(functionargs):
    # Call function(*args) and return it
    return functionargs[0](*functionargs[1])

pool = Pool(4)
functions = (add, sub, div, mul)
args = (1, 2)
result = pool.map(fmap, [(f, args) for f in functions])
print result
```

Just pass both the function and args you want to call in the iterator to `map`, and create a simple function that calls the function in the worker process.